# steps for deleting data in a table using django & mysql db

Tags: mysql, django-templates, django-views

I am using django and MySQL as a database for performing add, edit & delete details. I performed add & edit using the code below but delete is not working.

#### views.py:

```
import logging
import smtplib
from django.db import connection
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from polls.models import Poll
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from myapp.models import Book
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response,redirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.template import RequestContext

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def index(request):

    books = Book.objects.all()
    context={'books':books}
    return render(request,'index.html', context)

def addbook(request):
    if request.POST:
        book_name =request.POST['book_name']
        author_name =request.POST['author_name']
    publisher_name =request.POST['publisher_name']
    book = Book(book_name=book_name, author_name=author_name, publisher_name=publisher_name)
        book.save()
        return render_to_response('book_detail.html', {'books': book},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('addbook.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def book_detail(request):
    return render(request, 'book_detail.html') 

def editbook(request,book_id):
    if request.POST:
        book_name =request.POST['book_name']
        author_name =request.POST['author_name']
    publisher_name =request.POST['publisher_name']
    books=Book.objects.filter(book_id=book_id).update(book_name=book_name, author_name=author_name, publisher_name=publisher_name)
        return redirect('/index/')
    else:
        books = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
    return render_to_response('editbook.html',{'books':books},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def deletebook(request,book_id):
    if request.POST:
        book_name =request.POST['book_name']
        author_name =request.POST['author_name']
    publisher_name =request.POST['publisher_name']
    books=Book.objects.filter(book_id=book_id).delete(book_name=book_name, author_name=author_name, publisher_name=publisher_name)
        return redirect('/index/')
    else:
        books = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
    return render_to_response('deletebook.html',{'books':books},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

#### urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from DemoApp.views import index,addbook,editbook, book_detail
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^$', index),
    url('^index/$', index),
    url('^addbook/$', addbook),
    url('^book_detail/$', book_detail, 'book_summary'),
    url('^editbook/(?P<book_id>\d+)/$',editbook) ,
    url('^deletebook/(?P<book_id>\d+)/$',deletebook) ,

    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)
```

#### HTML template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ page_title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>   
        <div align="center">
            <table border="0" cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5'>
                <tr>
                    <form action="/deletebook/{{ books.book_id}}/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="text" name="book_name" value="{{books.book_name}}"></input><br>
                        <input type="text" name="author_name" value="{{books.author_name}}"></input><br>
                        <input type="text" name="publisher_name" value="{{books.publisher_name}}"></input><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="delete">
                    </form>
                    <p> Output: {{ output }} </p>
                    <p>{{ book_name }}</p>
                </tr>  
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not using any form in this. I am not able to perform *delete* operation for a particular row. It is giving an error message. Please check this snippet and revert me with correct one.

My requirement is that I want to delete the selected row from the table. I am using MySQL.

Comment: i need to perform this in view.py through python code..plz help me

Comment: code used in view.py to delete a row not entire table in db

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about django much but SQL Command to empty table is:

```
TRUNCATE table table_name;
```

it will re-set the auto increment to 1 and if you don't want to change that use:

```
Delete * from table_name;
```

and if you want to delete particular row then

```
Delete from table_name where conditions1, condition2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the values you obtain from your query first to establish whether or not anything matches your `delete` condition:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(book_id=book_id, book_name=book_name, author_name=author_name, publisher_name=publisher_name)
print '\n'.join([str(b) for b in books])
```

Why would you query on `book_name`, `author_name` and `publisher_name` if you have the `book_id` already given? I suppose you want to delete the books that match the given id (a bit more prose would be greatly appreciated in future). The query would be:

```
Book.objects.filter(book_id=book_id).delete()
```

Also, please make sure `book_id` is an existing attribute of `Book`. [By default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields), Django uses a primary key called `id`, `book_id` would be something that you manually changed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution for delete A row From a table in Django

## urls.py

```
url(r'^Books_Admin/$', views.Books_Admin,name="Books_Admin"),

url(r'^BookInfoDelete/(?P<Isbn>\w+)/$', views.BookInfoDelete,name="BookInfoDelete"),
```

/* Isbn is the Primary key of the table. */

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import BookInfo

def Books_Admin(request):
        books = BookInfo.objects.all()
        return render(request,"Books_Admin.html",{'books':books})

def BookInfoDelete(request,Isbn):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        BookInfo.objects.filter(Isbn=Isbn).delete()
        return redirect(' After deletion which page you want to see, put that url here in sigle qoutes ')
```

// Here BookInfo is the table name.
// Here Books_Admin define for view the table BookInfo

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class BookInfo(models.Model):
    Isbn = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key = True)
    Book_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Publisher = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    Availability = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

// Creation of Table BookInfo

## Html

```html
<table class="table table-hover tab">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ISBN</th>
                <th>Book Name</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Publisher</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            {% for Books in books %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{ Books.Isbn }}</td>
                <td>{{ Books.Book_Name }}</td>
                <td>{{ Books.Author }}</td>
                <td>{{ Books.Publisher }}</td>
                <td>
                  <form action="/BookInfoDelete/{{ Books.Isbn }}/" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                </form>
                </td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
{% for i in obj %}
 
 <a href="{% url 'product_delete' %}?id={{ i.id }}"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button></a>

{% endfor %}
```

product_delete is the function I've written in views.py

urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('page', views.page, name='page')
path('product_delete', views.product_delete, name='product_delete')
]
```

views.py file:

```
def page(request):
    return render(request, "page.html")

def product_delete(request):
    if request.GET.get('id'):
        i=request.GET['id']
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                        cursor.execute('delete from abc where id=%s',[i])
    return redirect ("page")
```

**abc is the table name.**

**page will be the location where we want to go back after deleting the product or entry.**

**Remember to import a library in views.py as:**

```
from django.db import connection
```

If you do not import the connection, your cursor will not work.

It will delete a particular product on your HTML page and also from the database.